# Sending push notifications in batches of group ids from Fire Base (FCM)?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Anyone can tell me how to send a push notification to a batch of group ids using FCM.

I tried

url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send"

```
headers = {
    "Content-Type":"application/json",
    "Authorization":"key={}".format(API_KEY)
    }

body = {
    "registration_ids":["group_id1","group_id2",...."group_idn"],
    "data": {
        "hello": "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Device Group Message!",
        }
    }
```

but it is giving me error.

> {"multicast_id":6704816187425274139,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}